# Node js in Linux Embedded

Tags: node.js, embedded-linux, yocto

Hi I'm trying to install `nodejs` in a [Pengwyn board](http://architechboards-pengwyn.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) (TI Sitara AM3354 ARM) after installing `Yocto Linux` successfully.

I don't know how to install `node` inside. I've tried `opkg` but it shows this error in the `MiniCom`:

```
opkg_install_cmd: Cannot install package <Packag name's>
```

I'm a bit frustrated and I don't know any page that can help me.

Any help will be apreciated,

Comment: Can you download and compile the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution is include nodejs before build image.

For include node, when you [run hob](http://architechboards-pengwyn.readthedocs.org/en/latest/hob.html), you must click on **view packages** and include nodejs.